# Module '"@ionic/core"' has no exported member 'setupIonicReact' while upgrading ionic 5 to 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to update my ionic React app to 6. I followed the instructions here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/upgrading-to-ionic-6#react

I did:

1. Step 1 `npm install react@latest react-dom@latest`
2. Step 2 `npm install @ionic/react@6 @ionic/react-router@6`
3. Step 3 ...
4. Step 4: I get:

```js
import { setupIonicReact } from '@ionic/react';
^^^^^^
ERROR: Module '"@ionic/core"' has no exported member 'setupIonicReact'.ts(2305)
...

setupIonicReact({
  mode: 'md'
});
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue:

```
import { setupIonicReact } from '@ionic/core';
```

should be this:

```
import { setupIonicReact } from '@ionic/react';
                                 ____________
```